# How to set maximum available width for Component Gallery in PowerApps?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-collection, powerapps-component-framework

I have created a Component Library with Gallery Control for Horizontal Menu. I want that when screen resolution changed, the horizonal menu use the maximum available width. When I use that Component, everything is working fine except the width of the Menu Gallery. If I add gallery in same screen(rather component library), it is working fine with same settings. Can anyone please review following setting and help me if I am missing anything?

1- Component Library

```
A- Component
Height = App.Height
Width = App.Width

B- Gallery Control(Horizontal) of Component
Height = 200
Width = Parent.Width
```

2- App

```
A- Component Library
Height = 200
Width = Parent.Width
```

[image]